# GNU install -d recursive?

Tags: make, coreutils

I have 3 commands to create the folders necessary in a `Makefile`:

```
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/app
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/app/scripts
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/app/scripts/network-service
```

Is there a flag I can use to put this into a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the last command should be necessary. `install -d` will create the missing intermediate directories:

```
install -d "$(DESTDIR)/usr/lib/app/scripts/network-service"
```

From the GNU `install` manual:

> `-d`, `--directory`
>
> treat all arguments as directory names; **create all components of
>                 the specified directories**

For what it's worth, BSD `install` also works like this:

> `-d`
>
> Create directories.  Missing parent directories are created as
>                   required.  This option cannot be used with the `-B`, `-b`, `-C`, `-c`,
>                   `-f`, `-p`, `-S`, or `-s` options.

Comment: doh, I should have tried that before asking. The code I'm working on already had the above so I just assumed it was needed like with `mkdir /folder/in/folder`.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride `install -d` works like `mkdir -p` in this respect.