# Install directories recursively with GNU install

Tags: software-installation

If I have a tree of files, under say `/usr/share/appname/`, how can I install them all recursively with GNU `install` and mode `644`?

I'm assuming that I'll first need to have [`install` create the directories with `-d`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402088/143394) as the directory permissions will need to be different (`755`).

Surely this isn't the solution:

```
  local dir file
  for dir in "${dirs_with_files[@]}"; do
    for file in "$srcdir/$dir"/*; do
      # install fails if given a directory, so check:
      [[ -f $file ]] && install -Dm644 -t "$dir" "$file"
    done
  done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s no magic incantation to make `install` install files recursively. `install` might not be the best tool in this scenario: you might be better off using `cp` to copy the files and directory structure, and then `chmod` to fix up the modes.

Comment: Or use `rsync`, e.g. `rsync -av --no-o --no-g source target/`

Answer (score 2):

I first create the directory tree and afterwards copy the files as shown in this function:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Install directory
# returns 1 on error
# $1: Source directory
# $2: Target directory
_install_directory() {
    local _src="${1}" \
          _dest="${2}" \
          _path=()
    # Directory does not exist
    [ ! -d "${_src}" ] && \
      return 1
    while IFS="" \
            read -r \
                 _path; do
        [ -d "${_dest}/${path}" ] || \
          mkdir -m 0755 \
                -p \
                "${_dest}/${path}" || \
            return 1
    done <<<$(find "${_src}" \
                   -type d \
                   -printf '%P\n')
    # files
    while IFS="" \
            read -r \
                 _path; do
        [ -z "${_path}" ] && \
          continue
        install -m 0644 \
                "${_src}/${_path}" \
                "${_dest}/${_path}" || \
          return 1
    done <<<$(find "${_src}" \
                   -type f \
                   -printf '%P\n')

    # symlinks
    while IFS= \
            read -r \
                 _path; do
        [ -z "${_path}" ] && \
          continue
        cp -fPT \
           "${_dir}/${_path}" \
           "${_dest}/${_path}" || \
          return 1
    done <<<$(find "${_src}" \
                   -type l \
                   -printf '%P\n')
}

_src="${1}"
_dest="${2}"
_install_directory "${_src}" \
                   "${_dest}"
```